# Webpack error when using react UI component of uppy (uppy.io)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use @uppy (https://uppy.io) file upload component but I get a webpack error whenever I try to use a UI element.

I have tried

`import { Dashboard } from '@uppy/react';`

`import { Dashboard } from '@uppy/dashboard';`

`import Dashboard from '@uppy/react/lib/Dashboard'`

but I keep getting several errors like these:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@uppy/status-bar/src/StatusBar.js 117:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (117:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|   return (
>     <div class={statusBarClassNames} aria-hidden={isHidden}>
|       <div class={progressClassNames}
|         style={{ width: width + '%' }}
```

Whenever I use a UI element these errors pop up.

I'm totally stuck, does anybody have an idea what the issue might be?

Thanks!